# java -jar ./target/jar vs java -jar ./jar

Tags: java, jar

As in topic, what's the difference between running jar within project folder and within target folder and how this can affect reading data from `resource` folder within classpath?

Is there any way to fetch path to the `resource` folder depends on from which folder we running jar?

Answer (score 3):

The location of your JAR file should have no impact on the classpath. So if your `resource` folder is packaged in the jar, you access it in the same way in both cases.

Comment: Just answered to the other question. There is indeed a confusion between classpath and filesystem location here. See Kevin Boone's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, an application packaged as an executable JAR will contain all the file-based resources it needs. The application code will use, for example, the class loader, or some resource management framework, to find those resources.

However, there's absolutely nothing to stop you coding an application that reads from the real filesystem, and packaging that application as a JAR. If that is done then, although the filesystem location of the JAR itself shouldn't make any difference, the current working directory very likely will.